# How to get current namespace of an in-cluster go Kubernetes client

Tags: go, kubernetes

How do I get the current namespace of a deployment/service using the kubernetes client-go API? It doesn't seem to be in the client object or in the config.

Answer (score 14):

Using

```
ioutil.ReadFile("/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/namespace")
```

works but is ugly, when the desired implementation is present in the `Namespace()` method of `inClusterClientConfig`. But how would you get that object starting from  `rest.InClusterConfig()`? It is only instantiable from outside the package via `NewNonInteractiveDeferredLoadingClientConfig`.

I see [kubernetes #63707](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/63707) which looks related but was abandoned.

Comment: If you are using operator-sdk, there is a utility method k8sutil.GetOperatorNamespace() in package: "github.com/operator-framework/operator-sdk/pkg/k8sutil". The implementation just reads the above file.

Answer (score 6):

Add this environment variable in your deployment config.

```
 - name: POD_NAMESPACE
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.namespace
```

This is using the [kubernetes downward api](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/downward-api-volume-expose-pod-information/#capabilities-of-the-downward-api)

Answer (score 3):

You can always set the context for each namespace and then read from kubeconfig on which context you are currently on:

Use the following code to find out on which namespace you are on:

```
namespace, _, err := kubeconfig.Namespace()
    if err != nil {
            panic(err)
    }
```

This will return the namespace in which you're.

For more information refer :

https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/blob/master/tools/clientcmd/client_config.go

Comment: Sorry for such a late response- im using a kubernetes.Clientset object, not a kubeconfig, as I am running the service inside a cluster. Not sure if this answer applies, thanks!

Comment: Here is a more accurate snippet of code which fit the same feature than the code above: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65661997/2784039