# How to get namespace from current-context set in .kube/config

Tags: go, kubernetes

I am trying to get programmatically in Go, the namespace of the current-context from ~/.kube/config.

So far what I tried is from these modules:

```
    "k8s.io/client-go/tools/clientcmd"
    "k8s.io/client-go/kubernetes"



kubeconfig := filepath.Join(
     os.Getenv("HOME"), ".kube", "config",
)
config, err := clientcmd.BuildConfigFromFlags("", kubeconfig)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

fmt.Printf("Namespace: %s\n", config.Namespace())
clientset, err := kubernetes.NewForConfig(config)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

But still no clue if clientset can give me the namespace I am looking for. From this thread:
[How to get current namespace of an in-cluster go Kubernetes client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53283347/how-to-get-current-namespace-of-an-in-cluster-go-kubernetes-client)

It says something of this to be done:
kubeconfig.Namespace()

Comment: Maybe [this](https://github.com/derailed/k9s/blob/5843f2678278c06113566ff9a3ffc0c45e97fa7a/cmd/root.go#L92-L121) block of code from k9s project helps you.

Comment: No it does not. In fact it take the namespace as a  command line arg, i believe.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found a solution using `NewDefaultClientConfigLoadingRules` and then loading the rules. This works if your config is loadable with the default client config loading rules.

Example:

```golang
package main

import (
        "github.com/davecgh/go-spew/spew"
        "k8s.io/client-go/tools/clientcmd"
)

func main() {
        clientCfg, err := clientcmd.NewDefaultClientConfigLoadingRules().Load()
        spew.Dump(clientCfg, err)
}
```

Gives you a https://godoc.org/k8s.io/client-go/tools/clientcmd/api#Config which contains the current context including its namespace.

```
Contexts: (map[string]*api.Context) (len=1) {
  (string) (len=17) "xxx.xxxxx.xxx": (*api.Context)(0xc0001b2b40)({
   LocationOfOrigin: (string) (len=30) "/path/to/.kube/config",
   Cluster: (string) (len=17) "xxx.xxxxx.xxx",
   AuthInfo: (string) (len=29) "xxxx@xxxx.com",
   Namespace: (string) (len=7) "default",
   Extensions: (map[string]runtime.Object) {
   }
  })
 },
 CurrentContext: (string) (len=17) "xxx.xxxxx.xxx",
```

For your information, `ClientConfigLoadingRules` is a structure with different properties to tell the client where to load the config from. The default one will use the path in your `KUBECONFIG` environment variable in the `Precedence` field.

```
(*clientcmd.ClientConfigLoadingRules)(0xc0000a31d0)({
 ExplicitPath: (string) "",
 Precedence: ([]string) (len=1 cap=1) {
  (string) (len=30) "/path/to/.kube/config"
 },
 MigrationRules: (map[string]string) (len=1) {
  (string) (len=30) "/path/to/.kube/config": (string) (len=35) "/path/to/.kube/.kubeconfig"
 },
 DoNotResolvePaths: (bool) false,
 DefaultClientConfig: (clientcmd.ClientConfig) <nil>
})
```

Comment: well, I found too

Comment: Regardless, I would still take a moment to thank you Francois, for reaching out to help me here.

Comment: Could you please tell me what are the loading rules ?

Comment: I have updated my answer explaining what are client config loading rules and the behaviour of the default one.

Comment: Seems you found a similar solution. Happy if I could help anyway :)

Comment: Thanks you very much.

Answer (score 3):

```
import "k8s.io/client-go/tools/clientcmd"

loadingRules := clientcmd.NewDefaultClientConfigLoadingRules()
configOverrides := &clientcmd.ConfigOverrides{} 
kubeConfig := clientcmd.NewNonInteractiveDeferredLoadingClientConfig(loadingRules,
configOverrides)

namespace, _, err = kubeConfig.Namespace()
```

Answer (score 2):

This code, based on answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/55315895/2784039,  returns the namespace set in the current context of the `kubeconfig` file. In addition, it sets `namespace` to `default` if `namespace` is not defined in the `kubeconfig` current context:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "k8s.io/client-go/tools/clientcmd"
)

func main() {

    clientCfg, _ := clientcmd.NewDefaultClientConfigLoadingRules().Load()
    namespace := clientCfg.Contexts[clientCfg.CurrentContext].Namespace

    if namespace == "" {
        namespace = "default"
    }
    fmt.Printf(namespace)
}
```

This code works fine on user side, it it is run outside the cluster. Check comments below to retrieve `namespace` for a pod inside the cluster.

Comment: `if namespace is not defined in the kubeconfig current context`. It is not correct. I am facing a problem that: I build a aks container in a cluster that running k8s in a linux server. The pod is created in non-default namespace(eg. **testnamespace**). inside of the container, `kubeconfig` will be automatically setup when getting credential of another cluster, so as current context, but there is no namespaces defined. However, when run k8s comments without giving ns, it will refer to the ns where the container was built on which is testnamespace

Comment: Solution above explicitely explains that `namespace` will be set to `default` if not defined. So it does what it says, and works fine if it is run on the user-side, outside of the cluster. In your case, your pod authenticates to API server using a given `serviceaccount`, so you can pick any random service account in current namespace and get its namespace for example: `kubectl get sa -o=jsonpath='{.items[0].metadata.namespace}'`. Be aware that the `serviceaccount` used by your pod requires specific RBACs to be able to list `serviceaccounts` in current namespace.

Comment: Thanks for your answer very much! I will look into serviceaccount try to find a proper solution for my case
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65941558/where-the-default-namespace-is-defined-setup-for-command-kubectl-inside-of-a-pod/65941903?noredirect=1#comment116591332_65941903