# Where the default namespace is defined/setup for command kubectl inside of a pod

Tags: powershell, kubernetes, kubectl, azure-aks, kubernetes-pod

**Background:** There are Cluster A and Cluster B in Azure AKS. Create a pod called **Agent** running linux container in cluster A in namespace **test** (which is **non-default** namespace). In the linux container, pwsh and kubectl are installed.

**Operation:** Get into the pod/Agent in cluster A (kubectl exec -it pod/agent -- bash), and get-credential of Cluster B, configfile will be setup with cluster name and user name, but **NO namespace**.
When connect to cluster B from pod/Agent, then execute `kubectl get pods`, the resource within namespace **test** is returned instead of the resources within namespace **default**.
Since, there is no namespace called **test** in cluster B, so no resource is returned.

So I wonder where the namespace **test** is defined/setup in the pod/Agent as the default namespace.

Spent some time try to dive in kubectl code in github, without luck..

I also tried to use alias, but it only works for bash/sh, not for pwsh, since I don't want to change command name kubectl, if I do alias kubectl='kubectl -n default', pwsh would stuck into a loop.

Any answer is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/access-cluster-api/#directly-accessing-the-rest-api-1):

> Finally, the default namespace to be used for namespaced API
> operations is placed in a file at
> /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/namespace in each
> container.

Simple test from a pod:

```
root@ubuntu:/# strace -eopenat kubectl get pod 2>&1 | grep namespace
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/namespace", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 6
Error from server (Forbidden): pods is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:default:default" cannot list resource "pods" in API group "" in the namespace "default"
```

Directory `/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount` is by default always mounted to pod and contains serviceaccount token to access Kube API.

Comment: Thank you very much! I found it! Do you know if there will be any problem if I overwrite the file? For instance, the pod doesn't work anymore, etc.

Comment: Oh. `/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/namespace` is a read-only file. Is there anyway I can specify namespace to `default` in a delicate way?