# Helm/Kubernetes - StatefulSet: is that possible use serviceAccount from different namespace

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-statefulset

Since the problem mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65941558/where-the-default-namespace-is-defined-setup-for-command-kubectl-inside-of-a-pod).

I am wondering if it is possible to refer `serviceAccountName: "test-sa"` which is in namespace **n2** for example to create statefulset in namespace **n1**

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: "{{.Values.ContainerName}}"
  namespace: n1
  labels:
    name: "{{.Values.ReplicaName}}"
    app: "{{.Values.ContainerName}}"
    chart: "{{.Chart.Name}}-{{.Chart.Version}}"
  annotations:
    "helm.sh/created": {{.Release.Time.Seconds | quote }}
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: "{{.Values.ContainerName}}"
  serviceName: "{{.Values.ContainerName}}"
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: "{{.Values.ContainerName}}"
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: "test-sa"
      securityContext:
        fsGroup: 26
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 10
      containers:
      - name: {{.Values.ContainerName}}
        image: "{{.Values.PostgresImage}}"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5432
          name: postgres
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: {{default "100m" .Values.Cpu}}
            memory: {{default "100M" .Values.Memory}}
        env:
        - name: PGHOST
          value: /tmp
        - name: PG_PRIMARY_USER
          value: primaryuser
        - name: PG_MODE
          value: set
        - name: PG_PRIMARY_HOST
          value: "{{.Values.PrimaryName}}"
        - name: PG_PRIMARY_PORT
          value: "5432"
        - name: PG_PRIMARY_PASSWORD
          value: "{{.Values.PrimaryPassword}}"
        - name: PG_USER
          value: testuser
        - name: PG_PASSWORD
          value: "{{.Values.UserPassword}}"
        - name: PG_DATABASE
          value: userdb
        - name: PG_ROOT_PASSWORD
          value: "{{.Values.RootPassword}}"
        volumeMounts:
        - name: pgdata
          mountPath: "/pgdata"
          readOnly: false
      volumes:
      - name: pgdata
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: {{.Values.PVCName}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't; they need to be in the same namespace.

This is a more general rule.  Whenever one object refers to another they generally need to be in the same namespace, or the target needs to be a cluster-global object.  If a Pod references data in a ConfigMap or mounts a PersistentVolumeClaim, those need to be in the same namespace; if a Service selects Pods by label, those need to be in the same namespace.  There are a couple of exceptions, notably around RBAC, but usually these things need to be deployed together.

In the context of a Helm chart, I'd just create a new ServiceAccount rather than trying to reuse an existing one.  If it uses the typical `{{ .Release.Name }}-{{ .Chart.Name }}` naming pattern there won't generally be naming conflicts.

Comment: Thank you @DavidMaze. So there is no way to solve the [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65941558/where-the-default-namespace-is-defined-setup-for-command-kubectl-inside-of-a-pod)?

Comment: This doesn't seem obviously related to your other problem.  The service account and pod also must be in the same cluster; trying to move the objects in cluster A to convince a tool that it should use a namespace in cluster B doesn't seem like a good solution.  (You can explicitly say `kubectl --context other-cluster --namespace default` if you know the namespace name there.)